# Could not load file or assembly Blazored.LocalStorage on Kestrel server on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, blazor

Very strange problem.  Of course, I have been dealing with this error for decades and typically it means the DLL is missing or the wrong version.  However, I am stymied in this case, hopefully someone can help?

I have a Blazor web server, and built a Linux-target deployment.  It runs fine on the Windows development environment.
It has been running for about 9 months through several updates, no problem on the Linux deployed environment.  The latest update today, I built and deployed updated code to Linux, which involved zipping the published folder, sftp to the target machine, unzip, chmod +x to the executable, and attempting to start the service entry.  The DLL is definitely there in the deployment package, and is there when I unzip (running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), but when I start it up, I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Blazored.LocalStorage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3c577f5cf869402a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Blazored.LocalStorage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3c577f5cf869402a'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I do a `strings Blazored.LocalStorage.dll | egrep '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'` I do get 1.0.0.0, so I can't figure out why it is dumping.  Since it is complaining about that file, it is definitely in the assembly manifest.

All the files are there with same owner, same group, same permissions, this is the only DLL I am having a problem with.

The web server has been working for months, and only stopped working when I stopped it and tried to restart it.  The things I tried after getting the error are:

1. Reverting code back to previous version and start.
2. Running apt-get update / apt-get upgrade, and rebooting.
3. Exporting shell variables for .NET and Kestrel startup parameters, and starting in a shell (same error)
4. Installing on a different Linux box - this worked.  I added .NET environment variables, Kestrel config variables, unzipped the Linux publication, and voila, it worked fine.

What's the difference between the one box it has worked on for months, and the other one?  Nothing I can tell, just one - Ubuntu 20.04 (first box) and 22.04 (second box).  Same firewall config, etc.

Comment: On second thought, this is not necessarily related to this DLL.  I restored the older code and tried to start it up, same issue with different DLL.  I don't know what has changed, all I did was stop the service, replace the code, and start it up again.  No idea why I am suddenly getting assembly not found.  I also tried running apt-get upgrade, and it updated .NET, but didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I did apt-get update / apt-get upgrade, installed all updates, rebooted.  Still didn't solve the problem - Kestrel won't start, complains all .NET DLLs are missing.

Comment: I am absolutely floored that I have gotten no responses on this.  If we move to .NET 7 with AOT, will that resolve the problem (as there will be no external references, it will be a single binary file)?

Comment: Try to set environment variable COREHOST_TRACE=1. And see if you'll get more info.